# How can I find if the 10s digit in a number is odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a number X in the range of whole positive integers, how can I prove that the 10s digit of X is odd?

Assume that for all numbers 1 through 9, the 10s digit is considered even, and for all numbers past 99, a tens digit of 0 is also considered even.

Whether or not the actual number is odd does not matter - only whether or not the 10s digit in that number is odd.

This has to be done programmatically, so I cannot simply look at the number.

Comment: Can you give us more background, for example tell us why you're trying to do this? The most obvious way would be to take the integer part of $X/10$ and reduce it modulo $2$.

Comment: Can't you just look at the number? Or do you know something about $X$ you are not telling us?

Comment: Yeah, if it is for programming just do x/=10 and then x=x%2, the value of x will be 1 if the tens digit is odd and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @dREaM Will that be true regardless of whether or not the original number is odd/even?

Comment: @Zibbobz, yups.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to take the integer part (i.e. "floor") explicitly. In other words `floor(x/10) % 2` will be $0$ if the $10$s digit is even and $1$ otherwise.

This is totally independent of the parity of `x`. In other words, you can think of `floor(x/10)` as a shift of the digits of `x` to the right.